# [py]testing Flask app with SQLAlchemy nested transactions in nested scopes

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, pytest

I want to have nested scopes for database access in my pytest tests, so that I can use a `module` scope for generating database things that are pretty much static and take a long time to generate, and `function` scope for things that need to be created and rolled back for each test. In semi-pseudocode something like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def module_db_session():
    # create db session
    session = db.create()

    yield session

    # roll back all the changes after the module is tested
    session.rollback()

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def function_db_session(module_db_session):
    # Create a nested transaction that is used for this function scope
    nested_transaction = module_db_session.create()

    yield nested_transaction

    # roll back all the changes in the nested transaction after the function is tested
    nested_transaction.rollback()


# Theoretical usage
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def createstuff(module_db_session):
    # Creates a lot of stuff that takes a lot of time to generate
    # and is static data in the database so generating it once for module is nice
    for i in range(1000000000):
        module_db_session.create_thing()

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def creatething(createstuff, function_db_session):
    # Creates much less stuff that is actively tested and changes from test to test
    # so the scope should be function here

    function_db_session.create_another_thing()  # this should be rolled back after the test runs
```

So obviously I tried doing the same thing in real code, but the SQLAlchemy transactions and sessions are still a bit too unfamiliar for me. Here's what I have right now:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def module_db_session(app, db):
    """
    Returns function-scoped session.
    """
    with app.app_context():
        conn = db.engine.connect()
        transaction = conn.begin()

        options = {'bind': conn, 'binds': {}}
        sess = database.create_scoped_session(options=options)

        # establish a SAVEPOINT just before beginning the test
        # (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_transaction.html#using-savepoint)
        sess.begin_nested()

        @event.listens_for(sess(), 'after_transaction_end')
        def restart_savepoint(sess2, trans):    
            # Detecting whether this is indeed the nested transaction of the test
            if trans.nested and not trans._parent.nested:
                # The test should have normally called session.commit(),
                # but to be safe we explicitly expire the session
                sess2.expire_all()
                sess.begin_nested()

        db.session = sess
        yield sess

        # Cleanup
        # This instruction rolls back any commit that was executed in the tests.

        transaction.rollback()

        sess.remove()

        conn.close()


@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def db_session(app, module_db_session):
    """
    Returns function-scoped session.
    """

    with module_db_session.begin(subtransactions=True) as parent_transaction:
        conn = module_db_session.connection()
        options = {'bind': conn, 'binds': {}}
        sess = database.create_scoped_session(options=options)

        with sess.begin_nested() as nested_transaction:
            @event.listens_for(sess(), 'after_transaction_end')
            def restart_savepoint(sess2, trans):    
                if trans.nested and trans._parent.nested and not trans._parent._parent.nested:
                    # The test should have normally called session.commit(),
                    # but to be safe we explicitly expire the session
                    sess2.expire_all()
                    sess.begin_nested()

            yield sess

        parent_transaction.rollback()
```

I've tried this a lot of different ways but right now for pretty much every one of them I get `sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This transaction is closed` for `parent_transaction` in function-scoped session, but I'm not entirely sure why. I initially had only one nested transaction in the function-scoped fixture, but since `db.session.commit()` closes the subtransaction if you're in one, then i created two levels of nested transactions and return a new nested-nested transaction every time a `.commit()` closes one... So I don't really understand why my parent transaction is closed at the end when I try to `.rollback()`. Does `.commit()` close all of the subtransactions then? How is the module-scoped fixture working then?

Thanks a lot if you can share some insight into this.

PS. My original module-scoped fixture is based heavily on this: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-flask/issues/70#issuecomment-361005780. Gotta give props where it's due.